# Can't Connect to Openfire server

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am trying to connect to an openfire server using smack API, I am unable to do so.

Here is the code:

```
public class Tests{

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    System.out.println("Starting IM client");

    // gtalk requires this or your messages bounce back as errors
   ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
   XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

    try {
        connection.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        //ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        connection.login("test@example.com", "setup1");
        System.out.println("Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);

    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        //ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to log in as " + connection.getUser());
        System.exit(1);
    }
   connection.disconnect();  
}
}
```

The following is the output:

```
Starting IM client
Connected to localhost
Failed to log in as null
```

It seems to connect to the server but can't log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection.login("test@example.com", "setup1");
```

You definitely shouldn't be logging in to example.com domain if your server is started on localhost. 
Try just:

```
 connection.login("test", "setup1");
```

But remember that to be able to login, you need to have a valid username and password. That means you have to create user "test" with password "setup1" on your server.

Comment: k...this works. so if the server were to be on actual domain, then i should be using test@domain.com to log in from the client device, right?

Comment: I think you are always able to login in just with a username, but test@domain.com should work also.

Comment: On the XMPP interface, you always need a domain. I have no idea if this API requires it, but i would humbly suggest that it's a good idea to use a domain anyway, for consistency.